# how to get query value from 1 row to use to another row?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is example query:

```
payment_Type    payment_value       cost_type      cost value
Cost I          100                 Registration       40
Cost I          100                 books              40
Cost I          100                 Lab                40
```

The **COST I** has 3 elements `Cost_Type` that have their own `Cost_value`.

I want to manipulate like this:

```
payment_Type    payment_value       cost_type      cost value     Payment_by_cost_type
Cost I          100                 Registration       40              40
Cost I          100                 books              40              40
Cost I          100                 Lab                40              20
```

The point is the I want to divided the `payment_value` into each `cost_value`. In the example the `payment_by_cost` becomes 40, 40, 20 = 100.

The lab `cost_value` is 40 but it can assign value is 20 because remains from the divided 2 cost type above.

Is it possible that I can use the value from `Payment_by_cost_type` in the next row record? I have been trying to insert the value `Payment_by_cost_type` to a temporary table but select cannot have insert statement.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? I've been consulting to DWH he said it must using Store procedure it cannot done by query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your table contains not only "Cost I" but other values so here is a query to output results for all groups (by Payment_type) in the table:

```
;with table1 as
(select 
t.*,
row_number() 
 OVER 
(PARTITION BY payment_Type order by cost_type) rn
from t
)
,table2 as
( select t4.*,isnull((select sum(cost_value) from table1 
    where table1.payment_type=t4.payment_type and rn<t4.rn),0) CumSum 
  from table1 t4
) 
select payment_type,payment_value,cost_type,cost_value,
case when cost_value+CumSum<=payment_value then cost_value
  else 
    payment_value-Cumsum                  
  end                     

from table2
order by Payment_type,rn;
```

## [SQLFIDDLE demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e799/2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some kind of order for your records to define in which order the payments should be applied

Once you have done that (i'm using ID in this example)...

```
select *
    , case
          when payment_value-(select isnull(SUM(cost_value),0) from yourtable t2 where t2.id<t1.id)<cost_value
          then payment_value-(select isnull(SUM(cost_value),0) from yourtable t2 where t2.id<t1.id)
          else cost_value
          end
from yourtable t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it step by step using common table expressions.

```
declare @t table (
payment_type varchar(20),
payment_value int,
cost_type varchar(20),
cost_value int,
cost_id int --for the ordering
)

insert @t values 
('Cost I',100,'Registration',40,1),
('Cost I',100,'books',40,2),
('Cost I',100,'Lab',40,3),
('Cost 2',100,'Registration',40,4),
('Cost 2',100,'books',50,5),
('Cost 2',100,'Lab',40,6)

--get count for each payment_type to determine last row
;with payment_value_cte(payment_type,payment_value,count) as
(
    select payment_type,payment_value,COUNT(*) from @t group by payment_type,payment_value
),
--use sequential index for each row in payment type
payment_value_index_cte(
    payment_type ,
    payment_value,
    cost_type,
    cost_value,
    cost_id,
    row) as
(
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY payment_type ORDER BY cost_id) from @t --assumes order is by an id
),
--get sum of each row for payment type except last row
payment_value_sum_except_last_cte(
    payment_type,
    payment_value,
    current_sum) as
(
    select pi.payment_type,pi.payment_value,SUM(cost_value) 
    from payment_value_index_cte pi
    inner join payment_value_cte pt on pt.payment_type = pi.payment_type
    where pi.row < pt.count
    group by pi.payment_type,pi.payment_value
)
select 
pi.payment_type,pi.payment_value,pi.cost_type,pi.cost_value,
--if last row calculate difference, else use the cost_value
case when pi.row = pt.count then pt.payment_value - pe.current_sum else pi.cost_value end [Payment_by_cost_type]   
from payment_value_index_cte pi
inner join payment_value_cte pt on pt.payment_type = pi.payment_type
inner join payment_value_sum_except_last_cte pe on pe.payment_type = pi.payment_type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT payment_Type, payment_value, cost_type, cost_value,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY payment_Type)
            THEN SUM(cost_value) OVER (PARTITION BY payment_Type) - payment_value 
            ELSE cost_value END AS Payment_by_cost_type
FROM dbo.your_table
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4eab/1/0)